# Headless Chrome Disconnects after running about 1000 unit tests

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, karma-runner, google-chrome-headless

So we are building an Angular 5 app which already has a decent size. At this time we are at about 1.2k unit tests to assure the whole app is running as it's supposed to be. However when running all these tests the Headless Chrome runner disconnects after like 950 tests.

I don't think that certain tests cause this to happen as when I comment out the tests at which it disconnects it just disconnects at some other tests. Also it's not always the same amount of tests that pass.

We already tried giving more RAM to the Headless Chrome runner but without any success.

The terminal outputs the following message when the error occurs:

```
20 06 2018 08:41:36.016:WARN [HeadlessChrome 0.0.0 (Windows 10 0.0.0)]: Disconnected (1 times)
HeadlessChrome 0.0.0 (Windows 10 0.0.0) ERROR
HeadlessChrome 0.0.0 (Windows 10 0.0.0) ERROR
  Disconnected
HeadlessChrome 0.0.0 (Windows 10 0.0.0): Executed 969 of 1200 (3 FAILED) DISCONNECTED (8 mins 2.619 secs / 6 mins 17.243 secs)
```

What could cause this issue and how could it be fixed?

Comment: can you try to get some kind of log output from chrome? Could be anything really. Are you connecting via localhost tcp?

Comment: I edited the question to add the terminal output

Comment: Did you resolve the issue